# Python program doesn't terminate while using modules Tkinter,pandas

Tags: python, terminate

Hi I am currently working on a project where I need to select a file, cluster the data present and plot the no. of points in each cluster using **plot_count()** function. Any ideas why the program doesn't terminate.
Following code is just a snippet of my project.
Thanks in advance

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def plot_count(list):

    index_list = [None]*len(list)
    for i in range(len(list)):
        index_list[i] = "Cluster "+str(i)

    s = pd.Series(
        list,
        index = index_list
    )

    #Set descriptions:
    plt.ylabel('No Of Points')
    plt.xlabel('Clusters')

    #Set tick colors:
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='blue')
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')

    #Plot the data:
    my_colors = 'rgbkymc'  #red, green, blue, black, etc.

    pd.Series.plot(
        s,
        kind='bar',
        color=my_colors
    )
    plt.show()
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)


def get_filename():
    from Tkinter import Tk
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
    # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
    Tk().withdraw()
    # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
    filename = askopenfilename()
    return filename

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import plotting
    get_filename()
    plotting.plot_count([40, 44, 56])
```

Comment: unrelated but don't shadow the builtin  list

Comment: Guess that as `show()`, matplotlib is opening a tk window and waiting for the user to close it before continuing. Does the plot appear?

Comment: changing **plt.show()** - -> **plt.pause(some_interval)** and then blocking the interactivity - -> **plt.ioff()** solved the problem. Thanks For the help guys :)

Comment: @501shades, if that fixed your problem then you should post an answer to your own question, doing that could help future readers who run into the same issue as you.

Answer (score 0):

changing

**plt.show()** - -> **plt.pause(interval)** *plotted figure would be displayed only for specified* **interval**

and then blocking the interactivity - -> **plt.ioff()** *Interactivity will be set off and program terminates*

solves the problem.